# Is there a QR Code/Barcode API that detects orientation?

Tags: qr-code, barcode-scanner, aztec-barcode

I see the Google Barcode API and want to use QR codes. But I want to be able to detect whether it's rightside up, rotated 90-deg, 180-deg, or 270-deg, and count these as 4 different values.

I don't think this API supports orientations. Are there any that do?

I want to build this into an iOS and Android app.

If it's not using QR Codes, it could be something else, but ideally square, not like a wide barcode.

Comment: You might check out Dynamsoft Barcode Reader SDK which supports detection of rotated barcodes. You can try out the [online demo](https://demo.dynamsoft.com/DBR/BarcodeReaderDemo.aspx) and see how it works. (Disclaimer: I work for the company)

Answer (score 1):

BoofCV's QR code detector gives you precise location of position patterns and alignment patterns. There's also a bounding rectangle.

https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Detect_QR_Code

Comment: BoofCV is quite easy to use. I recommend it.